# How to rename method name or attribute in codeigniter project with cascading?

Tags: php, codeigniter, refactoring, call

I would like to rename method name "saveDate()" in controller inside codeigniter framework 
this method is used in many different location across the project . 
Is there is an IDE or tool helps me to rename this method name without going to all files in the project who call this method???

Comment: Try not to phrase questions as yes/no questions...

Answer (score 2):

IDE's like NetBeans and PDT both have "refactoring" tools with safe rename in them, if you want to give that a shot. In Netbeans, you can also use the "find usages" from the context menu on any function name.

If you want to go old-school, sed is your friend--you just have to be careful if there are other objects with the same method name.

Comment: I tried Netbeans "find usages" it does not work for codeingniter project since that way of calling method in the framework is different than ordinary php project ..

Comment: Are you referring to the HOST/controller-class/function/params/.../ method?

Comment: Yes I am referring to HOST/controller-class/function/params/.../ method? especally used with MVC. 
Sorry for very very late reply!! but seriously it will be usefull to know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler)? Otherwise I can't see how you can change it easy.